# SQL query using formulae

Tags: postgresql, formula

I have table name emp_record_table using this I have to calculate the bonus for all the employees, based on their ratings and salaries (Use the formula: 5% of salary * employee rating). Using columns Rating and Salary.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you want a function that does it or just a query like this:

```
SELECT 0.05*Rating*Salary AS Bonus FROM emp_record_table
```

Comment: This should be the correct idea, but quite unpleasant if one or two of the columns are empty. Your query would not determine a number for those rows. I think you should consider this possibility, doing something like SELECT 0.05*COALESCE(rating,1)*COALESCE(salary,1) AS bonus FROM emp_record_table. Of course, this is not necessary if the columns are defined as not nullable.

Comment: True, I made the assumption that they would be non-nullable because that is what I would do with those fields. Having COALESCE is less efficient but more robust.